# Dispute over the efficacy of using public CA certs to secure SAML assertions

Tags: saml, pki, ca

Here's the question:

Is there any benefit to securing a SAML assertion with a CA cert? I understand how using a CA cert is of benefit when establishing the SSL connection over which the SAML assertion is transported, but what about a CA cert for the PKI handshake that occurs when the SP accepts the SAML assertion itself? I have one side contending that within the SAML exchange there's no way for the SP to iterate through the chain of trust to the root CA cert, while on the other side I have someone saying that it can.

Bonus points if you can point me to an authoritative source that supports your answer.

Comment: As no one seems to have another opinion. Maybe this is correct. What are the arguments you have heard?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you wonder if there is any point in using a certificate sign by a CA when signing the SAML assertion.

In my opinion you should not need this. When you establish the initial trust and exchange metadata you can include the public key of the entity in the metadata. 
If you can trust that the exchange of metadata is secure, you can just verify the signature against the public key in metadata.

I can not see how a CA would give any value to this situation.

Comment: Having a certificate signed by a publicly trusted CA helps establish a chain of trust.  This is crucial for things like web browsers which access hundreds of thousands of websites that exist today while also supporting websites that do not yet exist.  This is a VERY different model from a "SP to IdP" relationship which is effectively a closed system.  Since SAML assertions are signed by a specific party (the IdP), the SP should only ever trust assertions from that one party.  "Automatically" accepting assertions from some other IdP just because it's cert was signed is a bit too trusting IMO.

Comment: As I understand it, you agree with my opinion. Correct?

Comment: Yes, completely - I was just adding some other thoughts around it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree too. Although in [standard Shibboleth Metadata sharing mechanism](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Metadata#Metadata-RemoteBatchesofSignedMetadata) (Federation) the whole published metadata block is sign by Federation certificate. So PKI may be (and probably is) used to distribute service and IdP metadata between security partners. But as Stefan wrote, there is no point in signing Assertion with Certificate signed by trusted CA